# Prove that a function with $\cos(x)$ has zeros

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

## The Problem

I'm trying to find the zeros of this function in the $[0, +\infty]$ interval:
$$f(x) = e^{-x^2} - \cos(x)$$

## What I've tried

I know that $\cos(x)$ is a periodic function limited by $[-1, 1]$ and that $e^{-x^2}$ asymptotically approaches $0$ as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, therefore, both $\cos(x)$ and $e^{-x^2}$ have equal values in many points in the $[0, +\infty]$ interval . But i don't know how to manipulate the function formula in order to find the infinite amount of zeros of this in function in the $[0, +\infty]$. Any ideas on how can i do that? I've thought about reviewing some materials related to numerical analysis ( like the method of successive approximations ) but found nothing that could help me.

Comment: Try to apply Bolzano's theorem

Comment: Are you trying to prove that there are infinitely many zeroes or find a formula for the zeroes? If the former, you've already pretty much outlined a proof. If the latter, why do you expect there to be any closed-form expression for the zeroes at all? Many functions have zeroes that can't be given by a closed-form expression in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Yes, @DanielHast, im trying to find a formula for those zeroes, to trying my ability to manipulate functions. I would like to involve more mathematical notation in my proof.

Answer (score 4):

Consider that you look for the zeros of function
$$f(x)=e^{-x^2}-\cos(x)$$
The first iterate of Newton method gives
$$x_1^{(n)}=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2+\frac 1{(2n+1)\pi-(-1)^n \exp\left(\Big[(2n+1)\frac \pi 2\Big]^2\right)}$$
For the second root (after the trivial $x=0$), this gives
$$x_1=\color{red}{4.712388980611567581644190927}14$$ while the solution is
$$x=  \color{red}{4.71238898061156758164419092765}$$

For the third root, the difference is $5.25\times 10^{-79}$ and for the fourth it is $7.24\times 10^{-156}$.

Doing the same with Householder method, the second root will be in absolute error of $1.80\times 10^{-46}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. I did not count the trivial $x=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Sorry ! I don't know how I counted. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: You have the trivial $x=0$, you get a first positive root $x_0\approx0.92\frac\pi2$ in your schema, and then the second positive root $x_1$ that you discussed (obligatory [xkcd 386](https://xkcd.com/386/)).

Comment: Thanks, @ClaudeLeibovici! Just a question, what is the $n$ superscript in the $x_1(n)$ definition? The number of iterations or the root position, i.e first root, second root and etc.

Comment: @Occhima. $x_1^{(n)}$ is the first estimate of Newton methosd fpt the $n^{th}$ root

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I've been studying newtons method and i know that for each iteration $x^{n}_{n} = x_0 + f(x_0)/f'(x_0)$, in your formula is $x_0 = (2n + 1)\frac{\pi}{2}$? If it is, why it's not $2n\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge 1$, you know that $0\le e^{-x^2}\le 1/e<1$.

Now, you also know that $\cos(2k\pi)=1$ and $\cos((2k+1)\pi)=-1$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$

So, you can apply Bolzano's Theorem to $f(x):=e^{-x^2}-\cos x$ in each interval $[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

The Gaussian exponential is so quickly decaying that the solutions are essentially the roots of the cosine, except for $x=0$ and $x=1.4474142\cdots$.

For $x=\dfrac{3\pi}2$, we already have $e^{-x^2}<3\cdot10^{-10}$.

---

It is an easy matter to show that every neighborhood of $(n+\frac12)\pi$ of width, say $0.1$ for $n>1$ contains exactly one root.

Comment: Ty so much, can you give me a hint on how can i show that in every neighborhood of  $(n + \frac{1}{2}) \pi$  there is exactly one root of $f(x)$?